# no entity generate with reverse engineering on hibernate

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, mariadb

I've got a problem with reverse engineering on Hibernate.

I've this dependencies in my pom and just those two

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I've got this as hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">toto</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3306/</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">titi</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

my Hibernate reveng.xml look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
   <table-filter match-catalog="boutique" match-name="caracterise"/>
   <table-filter match-catalog="boutique" match-name="caracteristiques"/>
   <table-filter match-catalog="boutique" match-name="categories"/>
   <table-filter match-catalog="boutique" match-name="clients"/>
   <table-filter match-catalog="boutique" match-name="commentaires"/>
   <table-filter match-catalog="boutique" match-name="commente"/>
   <table-filter match-catalog="boutique" match-name="contient"/>
   <table-filter match-catalog="boutique" match-name="fournis"/>
   <table-filter match-catalog="boutique" match-name="fournisseurs"/>
   <table-filter match-catalog="boutique" match-name="marques"/>
   <table-filter match-catalog="boutique" match-name="nomcaracteristique"/>
   <table-filter match-catalog="boutique" match-name="paniers"/>
   <table-filter match-catalog="boutique" match-name="produits"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

and when I run "Hibernate code generation configurations" the computer work for a bit but I haven't got any code generation and I've got no error message

all my files are auto generate with jboss tool 4.5.0 final on eclipse oxygen and jdk1.8.0_144 32bit on debian 9

In the error log box I've got this message now

```
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
        org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
        Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try to console configuration. I'm using DevStudio, so I'm not entirely sure if this is the same as jboss tools on oxygen, though I know DevStudio uses jboss tools.

[image: jboss tools configuration]